# Algolia search query by field not working

Tags: java, algolia

I have an index like the below:

```
[
  {
    "startDateTime": "2023-04-13 02:10:51",
    "eventType": "Book",
    "event": "ABC Launch",
    "authors": "Nick Leeson",
    "startTime": 1681351851,
    "eventID": 100
  },
  {
  "startDateTime": "2023-04-13 02:13:00",
  "eventType": "Book",
  "event": "XYZ Launch",
  "authors": "John Davidson",
  "startTime": 1681351980,
  "eventID": 101
  },
  {
  "startDateTime": "2023-04-13 04:26:20",
  "eventType": "Book",
  "event": "NEW Launch",
  "authors": "Nicole Swift",
  "startTime": 1681359980,
  "eventID": 102
  },
  {
  "startDateTime": "2023-04-13 07:13:00",
  "eventType": "Book",
  "event": "Kids Launch",
  "authors": "Timothy Smith",
  "startTime": 1681369980,
  "eventID": 103
  }
]
```

When I try to search by "authors" using java sdk, no results are returned.
My code looks like:

```
Query query = new Query("authors");
query.setFilters("authors:'John Davidson'");

SearchResult<?> result = index.search(query);
```

The above result returns 0 hits. However the below query works:

```
Query query = new Query("authors");
query.setQuery("John Davidson");

SearchResult<?> result = index.search(query);
```

Can anyone please help me to understand what could be the issue? Also if I want to search multiple authors in a single query how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Yes i could that, thanks. BTW, do you have any example/sample using typescript?

Comment: in the docs you can look at the [javascript section](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/?client=javascript#apply-filters-on-a-search-query). typescript javascript both use the same npm package. also you could vote/accept answers if it helped so others can also know if worked :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have not configured your [`attributesForFaceting`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/attributesForFaceting/). `authors` should be set as an attribute for faceting. Whatever filter you use make sure you do the above. You can do this programmatically or via the Algolia Dashboard (In the index configuration -> Facets in FILTERING AND FACETING section). After doing that try

```java
Query query = new Query();
query.setFilters("authors:'John Davidson'");

SearchResult<?> result = index.search(query);
```

by the way if you do like

```java
Query query = new Query("authors");
```

it means you are searching for the string/query "authors" in the index. So you will naturally get 0 hits since none of the objects have that string. Your second example worked because you are overriding it to "John Davidson" using `setQuery`. Now it will search for objects having the string John Davidson and give you the hits. You can see for yourself if you print out the result and check the `query` field.

If you want to search by multiple authors you can use query language like `OR`,`AND` and so on.

```js
query.setFilters("authors:'John Davidson' OR authors:'Nicole Swift'");
```

you can see the [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/?client=java) for that

alternatively you can use [`facetFilters`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/facetFilters/#simple-or-filter) API where you can write array like notation

```js
query.setFacetFilters(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("authors:John Davidson","authors:Nicole Swift")));
```

but for any of that to work you need to set the attributes for faceting

Comment: @Spartacus cool let know if it didn't work. also i recommend if u haven't to add searchable attributes as well for the fields that you need to search only

Comment: I was having the issue in React library to show related products, but I needed to filter the products which were not active with the active flag, But could not get the results, after configuring the attributesForFaceting from Dashboard as mentioned above, I got the result, I wasted the whole day for this. Thank you so much @cmgchess for posting this answer!!